# Запись двумерного массива в одномерный python

Tags: python

Есть двумерный массив:

```
l = [[2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Как его записать в таком виде?:

```
l = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/406121/7485582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример кода:

```
l = [elem[0] for elem in l]
```

Если во вложенных списка больше 1 элемента то так:

```
answer = []
for i in l:
    answer.append(i)
```

Answer (score 7):

с любым кол-вом элементов во втором измерении

```
[a for b in l for a in b]
```

Comment: Красиво сделал, я думал также только я писал справа на лево, и мне писало что оно хз что такое b. Красавчик.

Answer (score 5):

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8],
          [9, 10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15, 16]]

print(sum(matrix, []))
```

#вывод

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Преобразование двумерного массива в одномерный:

```
arr = [[2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 9], [4, 7, 6], [5, 1, 3]]

x = len(arr[0])
y = len(arr)

lst = []
for i in range(y):
    for j in arr[i]:
        lst.append(j)
lst
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 4, 7, 6, 5, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[2], [3], [4], [5]]
l = list((np.array(l)).reshape(4,))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: У `numpy` есть методы "выпрямления" массивов без указания конкретного размера: `ravel()` и `flatten()`. Ну и использовать `numpy` тут как из пушки по воробьям. )

Comment: А без numpy в несколько строчек расписывать циклом лучше?

Answer (score 0):

для превращения многомерного массива я предлагаю использовать функцию

массив:

```
my_list = [1, [2, 3], ["four", [5, "6"]], []]
to_line(my_list)
```

функция:

```
def to_line(arr: list):
   out = []
   for i in arr:
       if isinstance(i, list):
            tl_arr = to_line(i)
            for j in tl_arr:
                out.append(j)
        else:
            out.append(i)
    return out
```

вывод функции:

```
[1, 2, 3, "four", 5, "6"]
```

*многомерность массива не должна превышать лимит рекурсии*